# Git commit ERROR: Repository invalid

Tags: git, github, octopress

I recently came across the octopress blogging platform and followed the installation instructions. I am hosting it on github using github pages.
I created a repository and successfully managed to make an initial commit.
My problem came when I tried to make another commit and this is the message I got:

```
Immanuels-MacBook-Pro:octopress manuweg$ git add .
Immanuels-MacBook-Pro:octopress manuweg$ git commit -m "Changed origin url"
[source e0fff54] Changed origin url
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
Immanuels-MacBook-Pro:octopress manuweg$ git push origin source
ERROR: Repository invalid.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This is the config in my .git/config file

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:manuweg/manuweg.github.com.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

When I do

```
git config --get-regexp '^(remote|branch)\.'
```

I get

```
remote.octopress.url git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git
remote.octopress.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/octopress/*
branch.source.remote origin
branch.source.merge refs/heads/master
remote.origin.url git@github.com:manuweg/manuweg.github.com.git
emote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

As you can see there seems to be a spelling mistake on the last line

```
emote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Which I assume should read:

```
remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The remote origin url is correct and worked for the initial commit.
Any ideas why I am getting this error?

Comment: So I solved this problem by creating another origin with exactly the same details as the first origin:

    git remote add origin2 git@github.com:manuweg/manuweg.github.com.git

Comment: You should post it as an answer if it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved this problem by creating another origin with exactly the same details as the first origin:

```
git remote add origin2 git@github.com:manuweg/manuweg.github.com.git
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the error by deleting the origin and re-adding it. hope this helps.
you should replace  and  with your information.

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/<applicationname>.git
```

Comment: Nice one for removing origin. I got a bit stumped on that but removing it and creating a fresh one is the best solution rather than adding another one.

Answer (score 0):

In http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/

Use this if you want to host a blog from http://username.github.com (though you can also use custom domains).

Create a new Github repository and name the repository with your user name or organization name username.github.com or organization.github.com.

repo name should be username.github.com, not username.