# GitHub "ERROR: Repository not found" when installing Octopress

Tags: github, github-pages

I followed the guide at http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/ to the letter, but when I get to the "rake deploy" part, I get this:

```
## Deploying branch to Github Pages 
rm -rf _deploy/index.html

## copying public to _deploy
cp -r public/. _deploy
cd _deploy

## Commiting: Site updated at 2012-08-21 18:04:11 UTC
[master 84293e9] Site updated at 2012-08-21 18:04:11 UTC
 61 files changed, 2658 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
 create mode 100644 assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/background.png
 create mode 100644 assets/jwplayer/glow/controlbar/blankButton.png
 (...etc)

## Pushing generated _deploy website
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

## Github Pages deploy complete
cd -
```

Any ideas where I went wrong, or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: look this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12554849/438504

Answer (score 1):

I have just encountered the same problem.

I guess in the following step，you exactly do what the shell prompt tell you do:
**chienlung@chienlung:~/octopress$** rake setup_github_pages

**Enter the read/write url for your repository**

**(For example, 'git@github.com:your_username/your_username.github.com)**

**Repository url:** *git@github.com:Chienlung/chienlung.github.com*

The shell promt about the repo url is wrong, if you follow it ,you will encounter the error:

**## Pushing generated _deploy website**

**ERROR: Repository not found.**

**fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

The right “**Repository url**” should be :*git@github.com:Chienlung/chienlung.github.com.git*

You should add '**.git**' at the end.

Try again with that URL, hopefully this helps.

祝你好运！

(Another:before you deploy your octopress, make sure that you have generated your SSH KEY.
About generating SSH Keys,see https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to remove this error.

assuming you have installed ruby 1.9.3

1. Create repo on github as `username.github.com`
2. `cd your_working_dir`
3. `rake install / rake install['theme_name']`
4. rake setup_github_pages 
     this will ask for repository name. Do not append ".git"
   e.g. `git@github.com:username/username.github.com` is perfectly fine.
5. Now add your remote repo, check available repo using
   `git remote -v`
   `octopress   git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git (fetch)`
   `octopress   git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git (push)`
6. Add your repo
   `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/username.github.com.git`
7. Rename branch master to source, because github pages publishes only source branch
   `git branch`
   `* master`
   `git branch -m master source`
   `git branch`
   `* source`
8. time to preview
   `rake preview`
   open browser and goto localhost:4000
9. if all is well then push to github
10. `rake generate`
    `git add .`
    `git commit -m "first blog"`
    `git push origin source`
     rake deploy

Answer (score 0):

as per your description, I think it's a git connection issue.
Just refer to one of your successfully connected project, go to .git/config and see the value 'url' key.

I got the same issue while I tried the formal steps with octopress, it generated wrong url, so I updated it to

**url = ssh://git@github.com/AndyEverLie/andyeverlie.github.com.git**

in [remote "origin"] section, then run 'rake deploy', it works!

my env:

- git version 1.7.0.4
- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux]

Wish this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you provide the rake task the correct url- the example url has .io trailing but the github pages url will likely have .com instead.

I also found that the rake task generates a .git/config where the remote origin branch url ends with .io, which should be changed to .com.git to allow you to push up your source code on the 'source' branch the rake task creates.